# taking first column of one file and making it the first column of a second file in perl or unix

Tags: perl, unix, merge, csv

examples:

file 1 :

```
contig01

contig02

contig03

contig04
```

file 2: (tab delimitated)

```
9.8 5.4 5.7 8.7 

5.6 4.5 6.4 4.6

3.4 4.3 2.4 4.5

3.4 3.6 6.5 3.5
```

I simply want a file that merges them so i get

```
contig01 9.8 5.4 5.7 8.7 

contig02 5.6 4.5 6.4 4.6
```

etc

the files are in the same order

Thanks

Comment: Show what you've tried. SO members will be happy to help if you run into problems and you're clear and specific in asking your question, but you shouldn't ask us to write the code for you.

Answer (score 3):

You want the [paste](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/paste/) command.

```
$ cat <<EOF >file1
> contig01
> contig02
> contig03
> contig04
> EOF

$ cat <<EOF >file2
> 9.8 5.4 5.7 8.7
> 5.6 4.5 6.4 4.6
> 3.4 4.3 2.4 4.5
> 3.4 3.6 6.5 3.5
> EOF

$ paste file1 file2
contig01        9.8 5.4 5.7 8.7
contig02        5.6 4.5 6.4 4.6
contig03        3.4 4.3 2.4 4.5
contig04        3.4 3.6 6.5 3.5
```

Answer (score 1):

In unix, use `man paste`

```
paste f1 f2
```